# Loop on sys.stdin

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I know I can't enumerate() on sys.stdin, but I have to do something like this without reading entire input in memory:

```
for i, line in enumerate(sys.stdin):
    line = line.split()
    if sys.stdin[i][0]=='something':
        foo(sys.stdin[i][0])
    else:
        foo(sys.stdin[i+1][0])
```

So, how can iterate on `sys.stdin` without reading everything into memory?

Comment: what is `line`? I don't see any action on `line`.

Comment: sys.stdin[i][0] is like line[0]

Answer (score 4):

You can use `readline()`, to get a single line at a time for `sys.stdin`.  If that is inside of a generator, a simple `for` loop can be constructed:

```
def read_stdin():
    readline = sys.stdin.readline()
    while readline:
        yield readline
        readline = sys.stdin.readline()

for line in read_stdin():
    line = line.split()
    print(line)
```